# How do I get charms in a dark room?

Tags: a-dark-room

I came across the swamp in A Dark Room but I don't have any charms. How do I get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get charms just by checking traps. The more traps you have the more resources you will get. So you get a higher chance on getting a charm by setting up as many traps as possible. Also using Bait does increase the yield of your traps as well.

For more info, check the wiki on [charms](https://adarkroom.fandom.com/wiki/Resources_(Browser)#Charm) and [traps](https://adarkroom.fandom.com/wiki/Buildings#Trap). Even though there is really not much more to it.